# how to refresh selectlist component in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

i have to refresh page when i click on save button using rerender attribute all component tags refreshing but select list tag not refreshing.. How to refresh selectlist tag..

```
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="out,list" status="actStatusId"/>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Custom Picklist Using selectList and selectOption" collapsible="false">
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCountry1}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="list">
               <apex:selectOption itemValue="NONE" itemLabel="--NONE--"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="INDIA" itemLabel="India"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="USA" itemLabel="USA"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="United Kingdom" itemLabel="UK"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: can you share your code here?

Comment: can you share your code btw you can use rerender for this.

Comment: What do you mean by not`refreshing`. do you want to set it to `none`?

Comment: What is your requirement? The options are hard coded in VF page, it can't change even if you refresh the page.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma Thank you for reply..yes yes when i click on save button select list value should be --none-- how it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to clear selected value so with using `rerender` from your save method clear the selected value.

```
//Save method code
selectedCountry1 = 'NONE';
```

Add this line in your Save method and it will clear the value.